# UISplitviewcontroller - Size class issue in Master and Detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uisplitviewcontroller, size-classes

While using UISplitviewcontroller in iPad.

Master view is taking Compact Regular Size class, while Detail is taking Regular Regular size class by default.

This is affecting the images used. Which is being used (different in size) in Master and Detail screen for same image

Is there any way that we can have compact regular size class applied on both of the views?

The images below shows that same images used for both view but it takes for different size classes.
[image: Compact Regular size image]

[image: Regular Regular size image]

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UISplitViewController` and override the function `overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController()`.

[Docs are here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController:)